# Increasing Function and Proof

Tags: functions

> If a function is increasing at x=1 and at x=2, it must be increasing
>   at every point between 1 and 2.

I know that is a false statement but is there any counterexample for it? I couldn't find.

Comment: Just pick a point between $1$ and $2$ and draw a function that's decreasing there, and increasing at $1$ and $2$, and connect the dots. What's so difficult?

Comment: I must find a function

Comment: What's wrong with a drawn function?

Comment: @user377054 Piecewise-defined functions are still functions.

Comment: So find one.  Draw *any* function that goes up at x=1 and goes down at x=2.  Don't worry about the *math* or continuity or smoothness.  Anything that can be *described* so long as one number is mapped to one number is a function. Simply say  "Let f(x) be an increasing line y=x at $x \in (-\infty, 1.5)$ and be the decreasing line $y=-x$ and $x \in [1.5,\infty)$.  That is a *perfectly* acceptable function.

Comment: "and connect the dots"  Don't even connect the dots.  Let the function be discontinuous.  $f(x) = x$ for $x \le 1.25$ and $f(x) = -x$ for $1.25 < x < 1.5$ and $f(x) = x$ for $x \ge 1.5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example: $\;f(x) = \sin(2 \pi x)\,$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is differentiable. Then an equivalent problem is to find a function whose derivative is positive at $x=1$ and $x=2$ but it is not positive on the whole interval $(1,2)$. Now, $$f'(x)=(x-1)(x-2)+0.1$$ does the job.

Comment: Although your example is fine, the problem you describe isn't technically "equivalent", since you can have a function whose derivative is positive at a point but not (locally) increasing there.

Answer (score 0):

Just take any function $g(x)$ that is increasing at $x=1$ and at  $x=2$ and define $f(x) = g(x)$ if $x \ne 1.5$ and $f(1.5) = k$ for any $k < g(1)$.

Examaple.  Let $f(x) =x$ if $x \ne 1.5$ and $f(1.5) = 0$.

That's it.

It really should have been a trivial question as knowing how a function behaves at two points says *nothing* about how it behaves at any other points, so you can define a function to be absolutely be anything  you want between $x=1$ and $x=2$.

P.S. A frustration I have is that students often have a naive idea that a "real" function has to have a algebraic of mathematical "formula" to define it.  That is pure nonsense.  A function is *any* mapping between a set $A$ and a set $B$ so that each element of $A$ is mapped to a consistent element of set $B$.

So to have a function increasing at $x=1$ and $x=2$ you just have to have it increasing at $x=1$ and at $x=2$ but doing anything you want in between.  It doesnt have to have a formula or be smooth or connected or anything.  Just draw a bunch of jags.  Or have you pencil "jump" down to another point.

P.S.  If you *want a formula.  $g(x) = (x-1)x(x+1)$ is cubic function, mostly increasing but with a dip and correction between $x=-1$ and $x=1$. It's increasing at $x= -1$ and at $x=1$ but not at every point in  between.  So just shift and stretch.  Let $f(x) = (x- 1)(x-1.5)(x-2)$.

P.S.S.  Also you shouldn't worry about the *exact* values $1$ and $2$.  Obviously there exist functions that are increasing at two points but are not increasing everywhere.  One can simple shift and scale them to fit into $x =1$ and $x=2$.

So for example take  $h(x) = x^3 + 2x + 1$

$h(x)$ is increasing at $x = -10$ and at $x = 10$ but not at all points in between so if $f(x) = h(\frac x{20} + 1.5)$ then $f(x)$ is increasing at $x = \frac {-10}{20} + 1.5 = 1$ and at $x = \frac {10}{20}+ 1.5 = 2$ but not at all points in between.

Or if $\sin x$ is increasing at $x =1$ (it is!) and at $x = 6$ (it is!) but not all points in between,  then $\sin (\frac {x-1}5 + 1)$ is increasing at $x = \frac {1-1}5 + 1 = 1$ and $x = \frac {6-1}5 + 1$.

But of course, that feels like taking a sledgehammer to a china plate.

More sensible is $\sin x$ is increasing at $x = 0$ and at $x = 2\pi$ so $\sin (2\pi (x -1))$ will be increasing at $2\pi (x-1) = 0$ or $x=1$ and at $2\pi(x-1) = 2\pi$ or $x = 2$.

But the idea should be a lot more obvious than any mathematics and calculations to do it.  Mathematics and calculations, despite the *years* learning them, are nearly *never* important.